# logstash index is not pushing data to ES

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

Wowwee.,big issues with logstash indexer.  Below is my indexer config file.

```
input {
  redis {
    host => "redis.queue.do.development.sf.augnodev.com"
    # these settings should match the output of the agent
    data_type => "list"
    key => "logstash"
    codec => json
  }
}

output {
        stdout { }
        elasticsearch {
                bind_host => "logstash.does.not.work.com"
        }

}
```

So..shipping to ES for use with kibana......where is the the data???????

Redis is being popped looking at the redis log si hte shipper is working.  Andthe indexer is poping.

```
1401264911.022972 [0 222.127.178.107:52248] "rpush" "logstash" "{\"message\":\"May 28 16:15:10 ubuntu shipper_test.py: {\\\"test\\\": \\\"aa\\\"}\",\"@version\":\"1\",\"@timestamp\":\"2014-05-28T08:15:10.998Z\",\"type\":\"syslog\",\"host\":\"ubuntu\",\"path\":\"/var/log/syslog\"}"
1401264911.026998 [0 107.170.218.65:42775] "blpop" "logstash" "0"
```

see in the log file on the indexer is the below and does not move

```
 {:timestamp=>"2014-05-27T05:07:50.980000-0400", :message=>"Using milestone 2 input plugin 'redis'. This plugin should be stable, but if you see strange behavior, please let us know! For more information on plugin milestones, test", :level=>:warn}
```

I mean....does what is the issue with?  Should not bind_host suffice?

Is is what in get in ES:

```
http://logstash.does.not.work.com:9200/_search?q=type:syslog?pretty=true

{
  "took":3,
  "timed_out":false,
  "_shards":{
    "total":0,
    "successful":0,
    "failed":0},
    "hits": {
      "total":0,
      "max_score":0.0,
      "hits":[]
    }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The data is save in your elasticsearch!
So, before your start your indexer you must start your elasticsearch. 
You can use Kibana to view your elasticsearch data. Please refer to Elasticsearch homepage.

Comment: How can you say its on ES when I get this result?  {"took":3,"timed_out":false,"_shards":{"total":0,"successful":0,"failed":0},"hits":{"total":0,"max_score":0.0,"hits":[]}}

Comment: Because your have point your logstash output to your ES. As you ask in your question, "where is the the data" !. Besides, you have use stdout plugin, if you don't get any logs event output at your screen, that's mean your logs do not send into indexer!